# How can I get value of DataTableCell in C#

Tags: c#

I have create a DataTable in C# like:

```
System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Rno", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("StartHour", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("EndHour", typeof(string));
dt.Rows.Add(1, null, null);
```

Table is filled with value now i want to retrieve value of "StartHour"
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Loop through your table rows and find the column for which you want the data

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    string StartHour = row["StartHour"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the Row, and on the Row you can index the Columns by index or name.

```
DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
string str = row["StartHour"];
```

Answer (score 0):

**There are 2 ways to retrieve value from DataTable based on Column Name**

```
var value1 = dt.Rows[0]["StartHour"].ToString();
var value2 = dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("StartHour");
```

Comment: you can also use an index if you know the position of your column. Like `dt.Rows[0][1]`.

Comment: yes, thank you for reminding. But he wants to get value from specific column name, so I just show him 2 ways